# AWS ECS EC2 Task Start Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

When starting a ECS Task, it takes around 12-30sec to get from creation of the task to start of the task. Docker Image in the task is from private ECR repository, and has 169.64MB. I'm using m5.large instance for EC2. [Task Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Rn7.png)

Is there anything we can do to shorten this time, between creation and starting the task? For example more powerful EC2 instance? Or some settings, optimization that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely be able to see improvements with bigger instances, however I suspect the time-consuming bit is the retrieval of the docker image from ECR; you can optimize this by:

1. Using a vpc endpoint for private connectivity to the ECR service. This will be faster than going over the public internet.
2. Enable enhanced networking with ENA for the EC2 instance

Useful links:

(1): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

(2): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips, I will try them out.

Comment: I found out that we already have VPC endpoint for ECR, and the AMI used has ENA enabled. And even with cached image it takes 12sec to actually start, when the image is being pulled it takes 20-30sec. Not really sure if it's possible to get like sub 5sec start.

Comment: @6972Honza are you sure the endpoint is actually being used though? Is the routing setup properly? Obviously if the image is large a certain download time is a given

Comment: I think so, yes. Pulling of the image isn't that big of an issue, as I can prepull the image, and with ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR = prefer-cached, the image won't be downloaded at all but used from the cache. It doesn't seem like there is much we can do, to decrease the actual start of the image.

Comment: @6972Honza in which case my advice would be to optimize the image size as much as you can, following docker best practices (e.g. reduce layers when possible, etc)